# How to find the best way to get a truly random sampling

Tags: powershell, sccm

I have a need for a Powershell script that will add a varying number of random clients based on operating system from 1 SCCM collection into another collection.

I've currently got it working without regard to OS so it's just picking clients out of 1 collection at random and placing them into the other collection.  I now would like to add functionality to randomize the operating systems they are running as well.  This is to get as accurate of a sampling of operating systems as possible out of a collection.

Here's what I have currently:

```powershell
## Get a bunch of objects (clients) with name and DeviceOS properties
$SourceClients = Get-WmiObject @ConfigMgrWmiProps -Class "SMS_CM_RES_COLL_$SourceCollectionId" | select Name, DeviceOS
```

At this point, I'm stuck.  I thought about grouping them all by DeviceOS, using a random array index to find random clients inside each DeviceOS grouping but I then thought of the possiblity that there may be a time when when I only need 5 random clients, for example, and there might be a total of 10 different DeviceOS groups.  How would I get a random sampling that way?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Are trying to pick a random element out of your `$SourceClients` collection? If so you can use `Get-Random` ie.

```powershell
$SourceClients | Get-Random
```

will return a single random object. To get 5 objects:

```powershell
1..5 | % { $SourceClients | Get-Random }
```

If you want to get 5 random clients from a random OS

```powershell
($SourceClients | group DeviceOS| Get-Random).Group | Get-Random
```

or a random client for specific OS

```powershell
$SourceClients | where {$_.DeviceOS -eq "MySpecificOS" }| Get-Random
```